# Como validar a data de nascimento pelo yup

Tags: javascript, yup, formik

Sabendo que a data não pode ser maior do que a data presente.

userValidation.js:

```js
export const UserSchema = Yup.object({
   date: Yup.date().required("Campo obrigatório")
});
```

html:

```html
<Field className="form-control" name="date" placeholder="date" type="date"/>
<ErrorMessage  component="span" name="date"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá!

Você pode incluir a função `.max()`, como abaixo:

```
.max(new Date(), 'Não é possível incluir uma data futura')
```

Answer (score 1):

Creio que para o `date().max()`, devemos passar a data máxima com o seguinte formato `YYYY-MM-DD` (ano-mês-dia) para o método `max()`. Neste caso poderiamos usar o método `toLocaleDateString` que viria no seguinte formato, por exemplo, `"08/02/2021"` e fazer umas manipulações para chegarmos no formato que o Yup aceita.

Faremos:

```js
const currentDate = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
const dateFormated = currentDate.split('/').reverse().join('-');

console.log('Data formatada: ', dateFormated);
```

A partir deste código, podemos criar uma função que será usada pelo Yup na hora de validar o campo de data.

Vamos chamar de `getFormatedDate`:

```
const getFormatedDate = (currentDate) => {
   return currentDate.split('/').reverse().join('-');
 }
```

Esta função espera receber uma data no formato `"08/02/2021"`, logo quando formos chamá-la dentro do `max()`, devemos passar um `new Date().toLocaleDateString()` com parâmetro:

```
const getFormatedDate = (currentDate) => {
 return currentDate.split('/').reverse().join('-');
}

export const UserSchema = Yup.object({
   date: Yup.date().max(getFormatedDate(new Date().toLocaleDateString())).required("Campo obrigatório")
});
```

Agora toda vez que formos validar uma data, esta terá o valor máximo do presente momento.

---

Caso você também queira saber, para informar uma data mínima aceitável, a mesma lógica se repetiria, basta informar o string de data no formato correto:

```
// não aceita datas inferiores a 1 de Janeiro de 1900
date: Yup.date().min(getFormatedDate('01/01/1900')).required("Campo obrigatório")
```